# How to obtain individual responses in FindCurrentPlaceResponse that can be later selected separately

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I need to make an activity that allows a user to click on getLocation button which in turn returns a list of places according to the likelihood score. the response from FindCurrentPlaceResponse returns 20 items which I would like them to be in form of a list or cardviews that a user finally selects the most appropriate location from. How do I make the response return individual places that can be put in a clickable list?

I have followed and used entirely the google places docs at https://github.com/googlemaps/android-places-demos for my activity

this is the exact code from the docs where the list is converted into a single string

```
@RequiresPermission(allOf = {ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE})
private void findCurrentPlaceWithPermissions() {
setLoading(true);

    FindCurrentPlaceRequest currentPlaceRequest = FindCurrentPlaceRequest.newInstance(getPlaceFields());
    Task<FindCurrentPlaceResponse> currentPlaceTask = placesClient.findCurrentPlace(currentPlaceRequest);


    currentPlaceTask.addOnSuccessListener(
        (response) ->
            responseView.setText(StringUtil.stringify(response, isDisplayRawResultsChecked())));

    currentPlaceTask.addOnFailureListener(
        (exception) -> {
          exception.printStackTrace();
          responseView.setText(exception.getMessage());
        });

    currentPlaceTask.addOnCompleteListener(task -> setLoading(false));
  }
```

Comment: I do not understand, it already returns 20 it considers to be likely; is that what you want on the list?

Comment: yes. it returns 20 but results are all combined into a single string displayed on the textview. what i need is to obtain single places that can be extracted individually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stringify does that. The response itself is already 'responses'. You may need an interface with a callback to add the results to a list of tiles.

```
// The callback interface
interface MyCallback {
void callbackCall(List<String> response);
}

// The class that takes the callback
class Worker {
MyCallback callback;

void onEvent(List<String> response) {
  callback.callbackCall(response);
   }
}

// Option 1: MainActivity or where the list is

class Callback implements MyCallback {
  void callbackCall() {
   // callback code goes here
   // update your adaptor 


   }
 }

worker.callback = new Callback();

// Option 2:

worker.callback = new MyCallback() {

void callbackCall(List<String> results ) {
  // callback code goes here

   }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I have checked stringify and it actually gets the 'responses' to a single long string. Any link or sample to such an interface would be really helpful.